# Help to understand the basis for a dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been introduced to the concept of dual space in linear algebra. I can understand perfectly that the dual space of the space $V$ is a space $V^*$ made of all possible linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. So, for example, let $V$ be $\mathbb{R^3}$, then we have, as elements of the dual space, for example:

$$F(x,y,z) = x + y\\F(x,y,z) = -x + z\\F(x,y,z) = 3z\\F(x,y,z) = 3x + 4y + 5z\\ \cdots$$

What I don't understand, it's why these things called functionals, span the dual space. I've seen a proof but I didn't understand. I know (at least have an intuition) that the dual space can be represented as the space of all possible linear combinations of $x,y,z$ like:

$$F(x,y,z) = ax + by + cz$$

but how to prove that this is suficient to generate the entire space? And why that rule that maps to $0$ and $1$ form a basis to this space?

Sorry by all these questions, but this concept seemed a lot strange for me, and I can't understand why dual spaces and finding its basis are so important.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo, but the dual space for a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ should be all _linear_ maps $V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Maanroof thanks, fixed

Comment: Does it also help your understanding? Assuming we are talking finite-dimensional vector spaces, am I correct you want to know why a dual basis is a basis for $V^*$?

Comment: @Maanroof yes, I want to know why those linear maps defined that way (that $0$ and $1$ thing) spans the dual space.

Comment: Well, you need to show two things then: linearly independence and the fact that they span the whole space. For the first, fix a basis $\mathcal{B} = e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ of our space $V$ over $k$, and let $e^1,e^2,....,e^n$ be the associated dual basis. Take an linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e^i$ equal to zero and deduce that all $\lambda_i$'s must be zero. As I recall this is fairly straightforward (using the $\delta_i^j$'s). For the second point, use that an arbitrary $\varphi \in V^*$ is linear, and consider what it does on $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but if $(e^1,\ldots, e^n)$ is the dual basis to $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ and $\mu\in V^*$ then $\mu(v)=\sum_j \mu(e_j)\,e^j(v)$ holds for $v=e_1,e_2,\ldots $ and hence or all $v$ (by linearity of $\mu$). So we get $\mu=\sum_j \mu(e_j) e^j$, a combination of the $e^j$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any linear map $fu$ from $V=\mathbf R^3$ to $\mathbf R$ is determined by its values on the vectors of a base $\mathcal B =(e_1, e_2, e_3)$. For if $v=\lambda e_1+\mu e_2+\nu e_3$, then $f(v)=\lambda f(e_1)+\mu f(e_2)+\nu f(e_3)$.

Now if $f(e_1)=\alpha_1$,  $f(e_2)=\alpha_2$, $f(e_3)=\alpha_3$ and if $e_1^*, e_2^*,e_3^*$ is the dual basis of $\mathcal B$, it's easy to check that 
$$f=\alpha_1 e_1^*+\alpha_2 e_2^*+\alpha_3 e_3^*$$ since both sides take the same value for $\,e_1,e_2,e_3$.